# query from two tables CAST

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query from two tables ...

The first table in which the goods are in the form of tree accounts ....

The second table in which the sale is linked to the first table.

For example, now I have the first table.

Question A sort query is required ..

I get the cars for their condition ... electronics for their condition

Of Table II.

With attachments, I want to create a query.

Database Script :

```
USE [To_Test]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Items]    Script Date: 11/10/1438 05:54:35 م ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [Id_ItemS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name_ar] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Number_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Basic] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id_ItemS] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sell_items](
    [Id_Sell] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Id_items] [int] NULL,
    [price] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sell_items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id_Sell] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (1, N'Cars', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (2, N'electronics', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (3, N'Toyota', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (4, N'Nissan', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (5, N'Camry', 3, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (6, N'2015', 5, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (7, N'2016', 5, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (8, N'2017', 5, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (9, N'TV', 2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (10, N'LG', 9, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS], [Name_ar], [Number_Id], [Basic]) VALUES (11, N'Samsung', 9, 0)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Sell_items] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Sell_items] ([Id_Sell], [Id_items], [price]) VALUES (1, 11, 2500.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[Sell_items] ([Id_Sell], [Id_items], [price]) VALUES (2, 10, 2300.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[Sell_items] ([Id_Sell], [Id_items], [price]) VALUES (3, 6, 20000.0000)
INSERT [dbo].[Sell_items] ([Id_Sell], [Id_items], [price]) VALUES (4, 7, 270000.0000)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Sell_items] OFF
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Items1] FOREIGN KEY([Number_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Items1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sell_items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sell_items_Items] FOREIGN KEY([Id_items])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([Id_ItemS])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sell_items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Sell_items_Items]
GO
```

view

```
WITH Recursive_CTE AS (
SELECT        Items.Id_ItemS, Items.Name_ar, Items.Number_Id, 1 AS RecursionLevel, CAST(Items.Id_ItemS AS varchar(100)) AS Hierarchy, Sell_items.Id_Sell
FROM            Items INNER JOIN
                         Sell_items ON Items.Id_ItemS = Sell_items.Id_items
WHERE        (Items.Id_ItemS = 1)
 UNION ALL
SELECT        Items.Id_ItemS, Items.Name_ar, Items.Number_Id, 1 AS RecursionLevel, CAST(Hierarchy + ':' + CAST(Items.Id_ItemS AS varchar(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS Hierarchy, Sell_items.Id_Sell
FROM            Recursive_CTE AS parent INNER JOIN
                         Items ON parent.Id_items = Items.Number_Id INNER JOIN
                         Sell_items ON Items.Id_ItemS = Sell_items.Id_items )
SELECT * FROM Recursive_CTE ORDER BY Hierarchy
```

**but The result is null**

I wish to modify the query ?

The desired result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R8mI.jpg)

Comment: I don't get the *question*.  Provide sample data, desired results, and explain the processing you want to do.

Comment: I want to modify the query

Comment: we know you want to modify the query and we want to help. Improve your question by adding sample data and desired results (with proper format please!) that way we can understand your question better.

Comment: please Help ... you test

Comment: modify the above SQL Server recursive query in order to add some detail information about the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to answer the question, very excellent

```
WITH Recursive_CTE (Id_ItemS,Name_ar,Number_Id,RecursionLevel,Hierarchy) AS (
SELECT        Items.Id_ItemS, Items.Name_ar, Items.Number_Id, 1 AS RecursionLevel, CAST(Items.Id_ItemS AS varchar(100)) AS Hierarchy
FROM            Items
where (Id_ItemS=1)
 UNION ALL
SELECT        Items.Id_ItemS, Items.Name_ar, Items.Number_Id, RecursionLevel+1 AS RecursionLevel, CAST(Hierarchy + ':' + CAST(Items.Id_ItemS AS varchar(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS Hierarchyss
FROM            Recursive_CTE AS parent INNER JOIN
                         Items ON parent.Id_items = Items.Number_Id)
SELECT        Id_ItemS, Name_ar, Number_Id, RecursionLevel, Hierarchy, Sell_items.Id_Sell, Sell_items.price, Sell_items.Id_items2
FROM           Recursive_CTE  INNER JOIN
                      Sell_items    ON Sell_items.Id_items2 = Recursive_CTE.Id_items
ORDER BY Hierarchy
```

---

### The result

```
Id_ItemS    Name_ar Number_Id   RecursionLevel  Hierarchy   Id_Sell price   Id_items2
6   2015    5   4   1:3:5:6 3   20000.00    6
7   2016    5   4   1:3:5:7 4   270000.00   7
7   2016    5   4   1:3:5:7 5   998877.00   7
```

Answer (score 0):

I see it as data issue. You don't have any records which satisfy your query.

I don't see any `items.Id_ItemS = 1` after Inner join on two tables - `Items, Sell_items`

```
  SELECT 
       Items.Id_ItemS, 
       Items.Name_ar, 
       Items.Number_Id, 
       1 AS RecursionLevel, 
       CAST(Items.Id_ItemS AS varchar(100)) AS Hierarchy,
       Sell_items.Id_Sell 
  FROM  Items INNER JOIN Sell_items ON Items.Id_ItemS = Sell_items.Id_items
       WHERE (Items.Id_ItemS = 1)
```

If you remove the where conditions (Items.Id_ItemS = 1) you will get results.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: But I want a hierarchy of id

Comment: @Abdullah I didn't exactly understand your requirements

Comment: See the last query on this site http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx  But this is one table .. I want two tables .

Comment: http://www.kodyaz.com/images/t-sql-samples/sql-server-recursion-with-cte-recursive-query.png

Comment: I understood that. you don't have any data associated with car item or itemid =1 in sell_items table. As you get empty records in first query the second query you inner joining with first query result set after union all .

Answer (score 0):

Add the following 3 inserts to Sell_items and you'll get results...

```
INSERT dbo.Sell_items (Id_Sell, Id_items, price) VALUES (5, 1, 270000.0000);
INSERT dbo.Sell_items (Id_Sell, Id_items, price) VALUES (6, 3, 280000.0000);
INSERT dbo.Sell_items (Id_Sell, Id_items, price) VALUES (7, 4, 290000.0000);
```

Also note that you aren't incriminating your RecursionLevel column. You'll want to add 1 to the previous value...

```
parent.RecursionLevel + 1 AS RecursionLevel,
```